# ExpandableListView children width

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

[image]I have an ExpandableListView in my app. I want to make the child layout a bit narrower than the group header and also keep it centered. Due to some visual effects i must set layout params from code however i can't seem to find the best solutions for this tried changing  layout width from xml with no luck. Any advice will be helpful.
Thanks

adapter getChild() method:

```
 @Override
  public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int 
childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, 
ViewGroup parent) {

    final Item expandedListitem = (Item) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    Drawable drawable= ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.background_border);
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable= (GradientDrawable) drawable;
    gradientDrawable.setStroke(5,expandedListitem.getColor());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        }


        if (!isLastChild) {
            View divider = convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearfaq);
            divider.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = convertView.getLayoutParams();
            int width = (MainActivity.display.getWidth());
            params.height = 110;
            params.width=width-40;
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
             convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
            View padder = convertView.findViewById(R.id.padder);
            padder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {
            View divider = convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearfaq);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 


[![enter image description here][1]][1]RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            int width = (MainActivity.display.getWidth());
            params.height = 140;
            params.width=width-40;
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);               
            convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
            divider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            View padder = convertView.findViewById(R.id.padder);
            padder.setBackgroundColor(expandedListitem.getColor());
            padder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }else{
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_low, null);

        }
    }
```

Item layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@color/back" >

  <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"

  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"


>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
/>
<TextView
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkbox"
    android:id="@+id/list_text"/>
 <ImageButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/del"
     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
     android:background="@null"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="20dp"

        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="+" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plus" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantity"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="-" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearfaq"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/back"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/padder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
     android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="2dp"

    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearfaq"
    >


</RelativeLayout>
```

category layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/parent_border">
   <TextView
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/cat_text"/>
```

Comment: have you tried using constraintlayout as base layout instead of relativelayout? In my experience, it's easier to work with for the things you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i wiill try to adapt contraint layout but can you specify any instructions on achieving the centered view?

Answer (score 1):

I'd put all Views in one single ConstraintLayout. By attaching the background to the parent left and right, the View is default centered. By adding margins left and right, you achieve the View being smaller.

Like in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:buttonTint="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Stuff"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

which looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

the

> android:layout_width="0dp"

actually means the view will be stretched to match the constraints. A bit like "match_parent", but within the bounds you set via its constraints.

Play around with the ConstraintLayout a bit. Once you get the hang of it, you will not want to miss it anymore :)

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. i think the problem is related to the ConvertView inflater

Comment: Which params are you using now in the constraintlayout to center the View?